# What are useful brush dynamics and tool presets in GIMP 2.8?

Tags: gimp, drawing-tablet, brush

In previous versions of GIMP only pressure was recognized by the brush tool. It wasn't much but it was simple. The new GIMP 2.8 introduces an all new brush dynamics system with a ton of customization and presets. I want to take advantage of it all, but I've gotten lost in the complexity, and the dynamics and tool presets that the new GIMP ships with don't seem to be any good, or at least I can't figure out what they're good for.

So, those of you who have figured the new GIMP out: **which dynamics presets should be used when and in combination with which brush settings?** Any cool custom presets that I should know about?

I'm using a Wacom Intuos 3 which reports both pressure and tilt. I've never used any other graphics program other than GIMP. I'm mostly drawing [flat shaded, thick border cartoons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdnNf.png) as a hobby.

Answer (score 3):

Dynamics presets as standalone are seldom useful. They do make a lot of sense tho when used in full tool presets, so I recommend starting there. There must be something that makes sense for your uses.

There are also several preset packs around. You can try them out and learn how they do what they do. :) http://libregraphicsworld.org/blog/entry/gimp-paint-studio-updated-for-gimp-2.8 is about such pack.

As to some ideas...
As a cartoonist, you may like maping size to velocity, that will easily allow you to do tappering strokes and in general various size mapings for hard lines and various opacity mapings for shading. If you have Wacom 3 Airbrush you might enjoy maping somethin you'd use a slider to controll to the wheel. If you have the Artpen, you will get most fun out of mapping rotation to the wheel.

Comment: Hi Alexia, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!